# Add bottom margin or scroll past last line in Mac OS Terminal

Tags: terminal, macos

If I have a full terminal history then the cursor will line up at the very bottom of the window.  I generally prefer working more toward the middle of the page.  Especially since I usually keep the terminal in the bottom right quadrant, it feels like I'm falling off the page to type in the terminal.

I'd like to be able to scroll down past the last line or add a bottom margin for new commands

**Here's a normal terminal window**:

[image: Normal Terminal]

**Here's what I'd like instead**:

[image: Scrolled Terminal]

**Note**: I know I can clear history with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, but that's more of a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I here what you're saying however the only thing I know of is to use the `clear` command.  It keep's the history intact while returning the prompt to the top of the Terminal window.

I added an alias for `clear` to my `~/.profile` file. Or `~/.bash_profile` file if using it instead.

```
alias c='clear'
```

Now I just press <kbd>C</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Then scroll back into the history as needed.

Comment: I'll leave open for now in case anyone has any other ideas, but `clear` is much better than Ctrl + K because it leaves the history intact.  It still requires manual intervention, but  pretty much does everything else I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: @KyleMit, Because of the _manual intervention_ this is why I use an alias for the command, since pressing two keys in this case is easier/faster then pressing 5 keys. :)